# Android - custom row layout in my ListPreference

Tags: android, listpreference, preference-v7

In my Android application, I have implemented class `SubtitleColorListPreference` which extends from `ListPreference`. I need this, because I need to set my own layout for each item in list. Everything works fine and it looks like this:

[image: Custom layout in ListPreference]

The important code is in method `onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder)`, where I set my own `ListAdapter`.

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder) {
    // some other code is here ...
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new SubtitleColorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.subtitle_color_preference_item, colorNameHolders, index, this);
    builder.setAdapter(listAdapter, this);
}
```

Now, I need to use `PreferenceFragmentCompat` instead of `PreferenceFragment`, so my `SubtitleColorListPreference` has to extend `android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference`. And here is the problem - there are no `onPrepareDialogBuilder` method in this `ListPreference`. Also, I did not find any similar method. I tried to find some examples how to create custom `android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference`, but with no success. 
Does anybody know how can I solve this?

Comment: I face the same problem, Did you find any solution?

Comment: I tried to use setOnPreferenceClickListener, and  public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        Object f = ListPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat.newInstance(preference.getKey());
        ListPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat dialogFragment=((ListPreferenceDialogFragmentCompat)f);
        Dialog dialog= dialogFragment.getDialog();
        return false;
    }, but dialog return null

Answer (score 0):

Google thinks that you don't need a custom view in `ListPreference`. It seems, the only way is to use the deprecated `PreferenceFragment` and `android.preference.ListPreference` or stay with obsolete SDK 27. It's clear that they don't understand what they're doing.